# Access Linux shell on a Gitlab server remotely

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gitlab

We have a GitLab CE server set up at my company on a remote server. I was one of many users, everyone else has left and now I'm the only user. I do have Admin privileges and can do anything on the front end that I need via the web interface (add users, add projects, etc.). Unfortunately, there's no one here left to do anything on the "back-end" (e.g. update the GitLab server for security patches), someone else did that and they are gone.

I have Git Bash on my Windows 7 Machine, I have an ssh client. I successfully set up the ssh client to be able to login to the GitLab server from Bash. Unfortunately, when I log in via SSH, I find myself in the "GitLab Shell". From here, all Linux commands (e.g. apt-get) are DISALLOWED, so I still cannot update the server. I believe the server is running on Ubuntu - but not 100% sure and I don't know which version of Ubuntu.

How do I log in to the actual Linux shell so I can run the updates?

Note: I do not have physical access to the machine (i.e. I can't walk up to it and do this locally).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "GitLab Shell" but my guess is that you just need to ```sudo -i``` once logged in to become root then ```apt-get ...``` command should work

Comment: No, sudo is disallowed like all other commands. Everything gets me a `GitLab: Disallowed command` error. Gitlab-Shell is a shell environment just for running Gitlab commands essentially. There is information about it here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/development/architecture.html

Comment: I am afraid you will need a user with sudo access or the root account of the host.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to discover and find and have user with root-privileges ("sudoer") for this host
- Only this user can transfer (share) his rights with you

It seems, that your company and last root parted in a bad way (it's always **The Bad Idea (tm)**), at least from my POV from here (remotely, with minimal information from you)... and your company haven't another good way, than to "make peace" with former root.

Well, you can (theoretically) also hire "white hat" Lunux-hacker, but in common case it can be **more expensive and unsafe** solution